# Error After Installing Gutenberg plugin (caused by attempt to stop WP from stripping out tags)

Tags: block-editor

I installed the Gutenberg plugin today to try it out.

I’m getting an error message both at the top of my WP dashboard, and when I go to view the site in a browser:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function ‘ikreativ_tinymce_fix’ not found or invalid function name in /home1/asharp/public_html/andreasharp.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 288

A few days ago, I got so sick of years of WP stripping out my tags when I go back to Code-View after switching to Visual — that I finally decided to find a way to solve that problem. I found somebody’s solution https://ikreativ.com/stop-wordpress-removing-html/

It didn’t work, so I deleted the file that I made with this suggestion’s code, and put my backed-up, unchanged functions.php file back where it was before I fiddled with this.

The warning message seems to indicate that the class-wp-hook.php file was changed by the code from the ikreativ site that I put into the functions.php file. As mentioned above, I did replace the ikreativ code with the backed-up, unchanged functions.php file.

I searched for   ikreativ_tinymce_fix     in my WP files, but it doesn't search file contents, so that didn't help. I looked for

I looked at line 288 in wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php. It is blank.

I’ll paste the whole section below a line of *** below.

The first line is line 286.

The indents don’t carry over the copy/paste step, so it might be hard to see that the entirety of line 287 is

```
$this->current_priority[ $nesting_level ] = $priority = current( $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] );
```

Then a blank line for 288.

```
And line 289 is foreach ( $this->callbacks[ $priority ] as $the_ ) {

********************************************************************

do {
$this->current_priority[ $nesting_level ] = $priority = current( $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] );

foreach ( $this->callbacks[ $priority ] as $the_ ) {
if( ! $this->doing_action ) {
$args[ 0 ] = $value;
}

// Avoid the array_slice if possible.
if ( $the_[‘accepted_args’] == 0 ) {
$value = call_user_func_array( $the_[‘function’], array() );
} elseif ( $the_[‘accepted_args’] >= $num_args ) {
$value = call_user_func_array( $the_[‘function’], $args );
} else {
$value = call_user_func_array( $the_[‘function’], array_slice( $args, 0, (int)$the_[‘accepted_args’] ) );
}
}
} while ( false !== next( $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] ) );
```

I don't know what to do to fix line 288 of the class-wp-hook.php file.

Hoping someone can send what needs to be there, and that I can just paste it in and save, and that it’ll fix the whole problem.

What should line 288 say?

Actually, how can I fix this?

Comment: There nothing wrong with wp-hook.php. In your own code you have an add_action() or add_filter() call somewhere, probably your functions.php file that references ‘ikreativ_tinymce_fix‘. The error would be because you deleted the ikreativ_tinymce_fix() function without the add_action() or add_filter() that hooks it.

Comment: You should raise this on the github issues for gutenberg, they can fix issues with gutenberg there or advise you better, but they don't trawl Stack Exchange looking for bugs

Answer (score 0):

Download a copy of WordPress and extract the `wp-admin` and `wp-includes` folders over the top of your existing folders, replacing them.

Then, you're left with the original problem to solve, which can be done by following the original blog post correctly. Filters and actions don't go in the `wp-hooks.php` file, they go in a plugin or a themes `functions.php`

Answer (score 0):

This means that you actually did not remove the code, or at least not all of it.

If you have shell access to your hosting you should use `grep` to search in the files for `ikreativ_tinymce_fix` this help help you to find the file that still contains that code. If you do not have shell access, use FTP to get all the site files to your computer and use a text editor with the ability to do a recursive directory search to search for it. If your hosting is nice enough they might help you with that, so maybe contact their support first.